# Speeding up pandas groupby aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id     count
A.     2
A.     10
B.     3
B.     13
B.     11
C.     2
C.     3
```

I need to aggregate, for each ID, the sum and mean of 'count' values. Using pandas, I'm doing something like this:

```
stats = df.groupby('id').agg({'agg': ['sum', 'mean']})
```

I tried to optimize this by using numpy arrays:

```
counts = df['count'].values
ids = df['id'].values
all_ids = df['id'].unique()
stats = [(i, np.mean(df[ids==i]), np.sum(df[ids==i])) for i in all_ids]
```

However, this ends up taking more time than the corresponding pandas implementation. Is there a way to speed this up (maybe using some numpy functionality?)

Comment: Is the dataframe already sorted by ID?

Comment: Do you mean `df.groupby('id').agg(['sum', 'mean'])` -- your current syntax makes no sense since you don't have a column labeled `'agg'`? Also can you give more information about why the built-in performance isn't cutting in? Those operations are mostly very fast to begin with, not optimal, but it's a tall mountain to climb to squeeze out a little bit extra. But it's possible that you're summing a `str` column (could be slow) or that you have a categorical with missing values that is really slowing things down when it tries to reindex in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only if your dataframe is sorted by `id`**:

```
# a = df.sort_values('id').values
a = df.values
a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
groups, indexes = np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)
values = np.split(a[:, 1], indexes[1:])
r = np.array([(np.mean(v), np.sum(v)) for v in values])
```

I think you can use `np.view` to sort but I don't know how to use it.

```
>>> groups
array(['A.', 'B.', 'C.'], dtype=object)

>>> indexes
array([0, 2, 5])

>>> values
[array([2, 10], dtype=object),
 array([3, 13, 11], dtype=object),
 array([2, 3], dtype=object)]

>>> r
array([[ 6. , 12. ],
       [ 9. , 27. ],
       [ 2.5,  5. ]])
```

**Performance**

For 1,000,000 values and 1000 different groups

```
id_ = np.random.randint(1, 1001, 1000000)
count = np.random.randint(1, 60, 1000000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id_, 'count': count})

%timeit np.array([(np.mean(v), np.sum(v)) for v in values])
18 ms ± 465 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```